# Invalid operands of types long long int and unresolved overloaded function type to binary operator+

Tags: c++

I am writting a simple experimental code in c++. But not able to figure out why is it giving me this error. Below is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long m = 100006L;
    long long ans = 243343435L;
    long long inv = 123455677L;
    long long x = 0L;
    bool succcess = false;

    for(long long p = 1L; p<10000000;p++){
        if((m*p + ans) % inv == 0 ){
            succcess = true;
            x = ((m*p) + remainder) / inv;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Whats `remainder`?

Comment: `long long m = 100006L;` should probably be `long long m = 100006LL;` (note the `LL` suffix).  Similarly for the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't declare a local variable named `remainder`, so the compiler thinks you are referring to the standard [`remainder()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder) function (that is visible because you included the non-standard `bits/stdc++.h` header, which includes everything and the kitchen sink), hence the bizarre error message (`remainder` has several overloads, so the name by itself is of "unresolved function type").

Comment: got it. I was wondering why the compiler is not throwing a compilation error related to an undeclared variable.